# Argparse with action='store_true' not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, scripting, argparse

The idea is to add a flag (`--slack`, or `-s`) when running the script, so that I don't have to comment out the `rep.post_report_to_slack()` method every time I don't want to use it. When I run:

```
$ python my_script.py --slack
```

I get the error:

```
my_script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --slack
```

Here's the code:

```
def main():
    gc = Google_Connection()
    meetings = gc.meetings

    rep = Report(meetings)

    if args.slack:
        rep.post_report_to_slack()
        print('posted to slack')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--slack', help='post to slack', 
        action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main()
```

Comment: Could not replicate, the parsing part works fine for me. But you don't actually use any of the arguments anyway.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding something, but isn't calling args.slack using the argument?

Comment: Oh, I see - it would be better to pass the arguments in explicitly (this makes it easier to test and reuse the functionality).

Comment: Phew. I thought I was going crazy. Could you give an example, please? (and, thank you for editing the code and the question)

Comment: What do you mean *"give an example"*? I'm telling you that *what you have seems to work*, please give a [mcve] that illustrates an actual problem or just delete the question.

Comment: Sure, you said 'it would be better to pass the arguments in explicitly'? Will you give an example of that, please?

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions, SO isn't a tutorial service. Again, can you actually recreate the error you're asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, but it relies on `args` being available in the module namespace, which isn't great because, for one thing, it means you can't use your function without calling the script from the command line. A more flexible and conventional approach would be to write the function to accept whatever arguments it needs, and then pass everything you get from `argparse` to the function:

```py
# imports should usually go at the top of the module
import argparse

def get_meeting_report(slack=False):

    gc = Google_Connection()
    meetings = gc.meetings

    rep = Report(meetings)

    if slack:
        rep.post_report_to_slack()
        print('posted to slack')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--slack', help='post to slack',
        action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args = vars(args)
    get_meeting_report(**args)
```

Now you can also more easily use your function outside of argparse by calling it directly.